# How to loop over the API for creating a generative code?

Tags: python, scripting

i'd like to experiment with code generation with the blender API, but i first need to understand how i could loop over the API within my code

for example `bpy.context.object` have tons of properties, we can naturally see those properties within the console autocomplete or within the Otuliner Data Api

[image]

[image]

**let's take a modifier for example.** (here above)
we can clearly see from the outlined or console that this 'Array' modifier have many properties (or functions)

i'd like to know how i can print each property module followed by the value assigned. 
something like so:

```
import bpy 

obj = bpy.data.objects['my_object']
mod = obj.modifiers['Array']

print('Properties of Array modifier:')

for modules,value in mod:

   print(f"property {module} : {value}"
```

i already saw this kind of [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487971/is-there-a-standard-way-to-list-names-of-python-modules-in-a-package) used before, but it seemed to only work with bpy and bpy.utils

```
import pkgutil
import bpy
import email

package = bpy.utils
prefix = package.__name__ + "."
for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(package.__path__, prefix):
    print("Found submodule %s (is a package: %s)" % (modname, ispkg))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well that was easy, **bl_rna.properties** is all i needed

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects['Terrain']
mod = obj.modifiers['Array']

for key,value in mod.bl_rna.properties.items():

    print('')
    print('Dict KEY  :',key)
    print('Dict VALUE:',value)

    n = value.name
    print('NAME      :',n)

    v = eval(f'mod.{key}')
    print('VALUE     :',v)

    a = f"bpy.data.objects['{obj.name}'].modifiers['{mod.name}'].{key}"
    print('API       :',a)
```

still the

```
a = f"bpy.data.objects['{obj.name}'].modifiers['{mod.name}'].{key}"
```

part is a bit dirty, i should be able to extract the API automatically somehow ? kinda transforming `mod.{key}` into the full API line.

code generation here i come

Comment: `repr(mod)` will get you the API string. Also `mod.path_from_id(key)` will get you `modifiers["mod_name"].key` so you can do `repr(obj) + "." + mod.path_from_id(key)` see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=path_resolve#bpy.types.bpy_struct.path_from_id

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the dir() method in python to access "public" attributes of any object. You can use it for each modifier in the selected object :

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object

for mod in obj.modifiers:
    print(mod.name, 'Modifier')
    for attr in dir(mod)[4::]:  # We skip the first 4 attributes which are internal
        print('  ', attr, ' --> ', getattr(mod, attr))
```

Exemple with an object with an 'Array' and a 'Curve' modifier :

[image]

Comment: You can also use `print(*inspect.getmembers(my_object), sep='\n')`